# htaccess mod rewrite for same URL with multiple parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have current rules in htaccess those works perfectly fine

http://localhost/branch/mechanical-engineering-seminars/ => http://localhost/portal/seminars.php?branch_link=mechanical-engineering-seminars

```
RewriteRule ^branch/(.*)$ /portal/seminars.php?branch_link=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now i need to add rules for below urls i have added them but it is not working somehow i think i am missing something.

http://localhost/branch/1/mechanical-engineering-seminars/ => http://localhost/portal/seminars.php?branch_id=1&branch_link=mechanical-engineering-seminars

```
RewriteRule ^branch/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$  /portal/seminars.php?branch_id=$1&branch_link=$2 [L, NC, QSA]
```

http://localhost/branch/1/mechanical-engineering-seminars/page/1/ => http://localhost/portal/seminars.php?branch_id=1&branch_link=mechanical-engineering-seminars&page=1

```
RewriteRule ^branch/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$  /portal/seminars.php?branch_id=$1&branch_link=$2&page=$3 [L, NC, QSA]
```

any expert in URL rewriting please point out what i am missing here.

I want all the rules should work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^branch/(\d+)/([a-z\d-]+)/page/(\d+)/?$ portal/seminars.php?branch_id=$1&branch_link=$2&page=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^branch/(\d+)/([a-z\d-]+)/?$ portal/seminars.php?branch_id=$1&branch_link=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^branch/([a-z\d-]+)/?$ portal/seminars.php?branch_link=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava, let me give try. Will keep you posted.